# What is fuel consumption of an A330 during climb and descent?

Tags: aircraft-performance, airbus-a330, fuel-consumption

I want to know how to calculate or estimate an aircraft's fuel consumption when climbing from sea level to 15,000 ft, followed by a descent to 10,000 ft.

I would like to see an example for an Airbus A330-300 with CF6-80E1A4 engines.

Comment: This depends on the aircraft in question. Your specific aircraft should have performance tables that give fuel consumption figures, but without that, it would be a pretty wide estimate.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Aviation.SE. Unfortunately we cannot answer your question here because calculating fuel consumption is covered by an *entire chapter* in a ground school book. It is too much for us to cover.

Comment: One approximation could be done with the total energy, the specific energy density of the fuel and the engine efficiency.
(sum of kinetic and potential energy in J ) / ( J per kg fuel ) / ( efficiency ) = kg of fuel

Comment: Thank you for answer,  do you mean kinetic energy 0.5*m*v2, and potential energy m*g*h?

Answer (score 2):

[Descent tables](https://www.mediafire.com/file/hoaj1lrg157kmdq/descent.pdf/file)

[Climb tables](https://www.mediafire.com/file/nc9izd5k42tp2gt/climb.pdf/file)

These tables are for the A330-200 and A330-300: in the footer of the page you can see for which engine these are. What you missed to indicate is the thrust setting, atmospheric conditions and weight to be able to give a realistic answer.

Comment: Thank for your answe. Sorry for late reply because i was not able to comment. What if Engine power is 304,7 kN each, maximum takeoff weight 233.000 kg while maximum landing weight 182.000 kg the data not enough? and for the tables where is the source If i want to get for another aircraft. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? The climb tables are up to 240000 kg and the descent tables are 150000 or 200000: you can either round your weight or interpolate.